# "Plugin not found for prefix app engine" when using maven

Tags: java, google-app-engine, maven

I am trying to run the command

```
mvn appengine:devserver
```

but it throws the following error

```
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'appengine' in the current project and in the plugin groups 
 [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local 
 (/Users/tylerrice/.m2/repository), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]
```

I have never used maven before all this code is from a development company we hired to write the majority of the backend so I am completely lost here. I visited the help page for this error [here](http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoPluginFoundForPrefixException) . I went through the list there and I can't find a pom.xml file either

Comment: I think you should start here: http://code.google.com/p/appengine-maven-plugin/ and let somebody introduce you to Maven too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

in your build life cycle you don't have this plugin defined you can verify it by

```
mvn help:effective-pom
```

and observe `<build>`

you need to let maven know what is this plugin and for that you need to add it to `<build>` like

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.9</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

---

**See [More](https://code.google.com/p/appengine-maven-plugin/)**

Answer (score 21):

So I had this same error. When I tried to run mvn appengine:devserver for appengine I was getting this same error

```
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'appengine' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (/Users/
```

I realized that I was up one directory too far, so when I was typing ls and hitting enter I could see my application. I simply needed to type cd [name of application] to go down one directory level to the application itself and it ran fine.

Answer (score 0):

In your POM file the appengine VERSION needs to be explicitly specified. (Not sure why).

> "
>          com.google.appengine
>          appengine-maven-plugin
>          1.9.15
>      "

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, nothing helped me, I worked around it by running the app server from the appengine home with the location to my app:

C:\Downloads\appengine-java-sdk-1.9.24\appengine-java-sdk-1.9.24\bin>dev_appserver.cmd C:\projects\google_app_engine\guestbook_tutorial\guestbook\target\guestbook-1.0-SNAPSHOT\